# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'filesize' was corrupted.- problem with file transferring over socket

Tags: c, file, sockets, runtime-error, buffer

I am trying to send a text file(that represent a lua file) via socket and I've encountered a problem where it said :
**Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'filesize' was corrupted.**
I saw some explanations about why it happened, but didn't manage to identify it in my own code , I'd really appreciate if you can help me out , thank you in advance!

**Client side:**

```
/*
============================================
General : function is responsible for sending the length of data to the server
Parameters : sock - socket connection between client and server
             *buf - holds a pointer to the data that needs to be sent
             bufsize - the length of the data pointer

Return Value : returns TRUE when the length of the data was sent correctly.
returns FALSE when there was a socket error.
============================================
*/
bool send_raw(SOCKET sock, void* buf, int bufsize)
{
    unsigned char* pbuf = (unsigned char*)buf;
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        int num = send(sock, pbuf, bufsize, 0);
        if (num == SOCKET_ERROR) { return false; }
        pbuf += num;
        bufsize -= num;
    }
    return true;
}

/*
============================================
General : function is responsible for sending the length of the file
to the server in network byte order
Parameters : sock - socket connection between client and server
             filesize - the value of the file size

Return Value : returns TRUE when the length of the data was sent correctly.
returns FALSE when there was a socket error.
============================================
*/

bool send_file_length(SOCKET sock, long filesize)
{
    filesize = htonl(filesize);
    return send_raw(sock, &filesize, sizeof(filesize));
}

/*
============================================
General : function is responsible of sending the new lua
file to the server
Parameters : sock - socket between the client and the server
             f - file that needs to be sent to the server

Return Value : returns TRUE when the file was sent correctly
returns FALSE when the file is empty or when there was a socket error
============================================
*/
bool send_file(SOCKET sock, FILE* f)
{
    if (fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) { return false; }
    long filesize = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);
    if (filesize == -1L) { return false; }
    if (!send_file_length(sock, filesize)) { return false; }
    if (filesize > 0) {
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        do {
            size_t num = fread(buffer, 1, min(filesize, BUFFER_SIZE), f);
            if (num < 1) { return false; }
            if (!send_raw(sock, buffer, num)) { return false; }
            filesize -= num;
        } while (filesize > 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Server side:**

```
/*
============================================
General : function is responsible for receiving a length of data from the client
Parameters : sock - client socket to receive the data from
             *buf - holds a pointer to the buffer that needs to update
             bufsize - the length of the buffer

Return Value : returns TRUE when the data is read correctly
               else, FALSE when there was a socket error or no bytes are received.
============================================
*/
bool recv_raw(SOCKET sock, void* buf, int bufsize)
{
    unsigned char* pbuf = (unsigned char*)buf;
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        int num = recv(sock, pbuf, bufsize, 0);
        printf("num = %d\n", num);
        if (num <= 0) { return false; }
        pbuf += num;
        bufsize -= num;
    }
    return true;
}

/*
===================================================
General : receives the length of the file and updates it

Parameters : sock - client socket to receive the data from
             *filesize - holds a pointer to the size of the buffer that needs to update
             filesize_len - the length of the file size pointer
Return Value : returns TRUE when the size is read correctly
               else, FALSE when there was a socket error or no bytes are received.
===================================================
*/
bool recv_file_len(SOCKET sock, long* filesize)
{
    if (!recv_raw(sock, filesize, sizeof(filesize))) { return false; }
    *filesize = ntohl(*filesize);
        return true;
}

/*
===================================================
General : writes to the lua file the data from the file
that was received in the socket
Parameters : sock - the socket between the client and server
             *f - the file to write the data received to
Return Value : returns TRUE when everything was written to the file.
returns FALSE if there's no data received or detected a socket problem.
===================================================
*/
bool write_to_lua(SOCKET sock, FILE *f)
{
    long filesize;//size of address
    if (!recv_file_len(sock, &filesize)) { return false; }
    printf("file size (From C client) : %ld\n", filesize);
    if (filesize > 0)
    {
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        //ZeroMemory(&buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        do {
            int num = min(filesize, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (!recv_raw(sock, buffer, num)) {
                return false;
            }
            int offset = 0;
            do
            {
                size_t written = fwrite(&buffer[offset], 1, num - offset, f);
                if (written < 1) { return false; }
                offset += written;
            } while (offset < num);
            filesize -= num;
        } while (filesize > 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Both `send()` and `recv()` return `ssize_t`, not `int`.  What is `SOCKET_ERROR`? [`send()` is documented to return `-1`, not `SOCKET_ERROR`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html).  How are you opening your `FILE *f`?  Is it in text mode, `ftell()`?  Because [`ftell()` doesn't work to get file size on text streams](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.4p2).  Please post a ***complete*** example.

Comment: including the `#include`s

Comment: Shouldn't you convert to/from network endianess consistently, both on client & server side, both when sending and receiving? Check the filesize variable in particular.

Comment: One error: In `recv_file_len` the `sizeof(filesize)` should be `sizeof(*filesize)`

Comment: @kaylum and it suffices, because apparently this is Windows code, hence `SOCKET_ERROR` rubbish. `long` is 32 bits, and pointers 64 bits on LLP64. Voting to close as a typo.